# Delphi one unique form for insert and update database record

Tags: delphi

In my app does I need to have separate forms for:

1. Form for showing data i grid
2. Form for insert
3. Form for update

Or I just need two: one for displaying data, and one unique for insert and update.

In unique insert form just pass selected id from row and with query load it in fields. First in insert form will declare boolean variable like `editMode false`. If passed id exist in db activate query and fill fields with values.

Is this good or bad practice? How big companies or skilled developers separate this?

I don't need someone to write code for me. I just want to know proper algorithm for this. Thanks

Comment: If you use db-aware controls in Delphi, you don't need to deal with your 1-3 differently:  you could have a TDBGrid to display a number of rows and TDBEdits to handle updates and inserts.

Comment: @MartynA i need two form one form displaying data and one for insert/update. How can i use tDBEdits in Insert form if is DBSOurce is in DisplayForm?

Comment: DBSource?  Do you mean TDataSource?  Anyway, it's a bad idea to try to use a TDataSource on one form from another.  Better to use individual TDataSources on each form.  The actual DataSet(s) should be in a TDataModule.

Comment: So in display frm one DataSource and in InsertFrm another DataSource?

Comment: Of course, why not?

Comment: Okay i will create FOrm that will display records in Grid, and than i will create Form for insert or update data and create new DataSource. Aafter that how to set values to TextEdit controls? Sorry but am not understant realy good

Comment: You obviously need a tutorial about Delphi db-aware controls: try googling for one.

Comment: @MartynA i create model and in model put query and datasource and just make relation in show form and insert form with DBEdit. Now is working, only what i need now is determine if form is for update or create

Comment: Thanks for the help i will try to learn more about db=aware